# How to start a computer when UPC comes back on power?

Tags: ubuntu, ups

I have a small Intel NUC computer in ny closet which I use mainly for Plex Media server. I have it on an APC UPS to be able for it to continue normally in case the house loses power for a short time.

Without the UPS, the machine doesn't have any problem to boot itself when it suddenly loses power and the power comes back later thanks to an "always-on" setting in BIOS.

But with the UPS the problem is that the machine is shutdown gracefully when the UPS has a low battery. The machine doesn't detect its state as a sudden loss of power so it doesn't boot automatically back and I have to manually press the power button.

I also realize that the power from the UPS is probably still on after it commands the computer to be shut down so it cannot boot back immediately because it'd be still running on low battery and would be have to shutdown again soon.

So my question is: When the UPS shuts down the computer because it's low on battery, is there any way to start the computer automatically after the power from the outlet comes back?

The UPS is made by APC, the machine runs Ubuntu and I use apcupsd.

Comment: "But with the UPS the problem is that the machine is shutdown gracefully when the UPS has a low battery." - Configure apcupsd so the machine is not shutdown when the battery is low.  You should also determine the reason your power is being interrupted so often.

Comment: But then the system is not shut down gracefully and for example the filesystem can get corrupted.

Comment: Power is being interrupted several times a year for unexpected reasons (like a storm or wind) and another several times a year for a planned maintenance. Nothing serious.